# Akka Cluster "Connection Refused" Confusion

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, typesafe-activator, akka-cluster

I've been studying Akka Clusters via the *akka-sample-cluster-app* tutorial and this [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/cluster-usage.html). I have it running locally (127.0.0.1), but I can't seem to get it working using my static IP (192.168.0.99). I'm doing this as a quick sanity check because I'm getting similar messages while trying to use my Raspberry Pi's as nodes.

> [WARN] [05/30/2016 11:01:41.432]
>   [ClusterSystem-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-8]
>   [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:63599/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2FClusterSystem%40192.168.0.99%3A2552-1]
>   Association with remote system
>   [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@192.168.0.99:2552] has failed, address is
>   now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Association failed with
>   [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@192.168.0.99:2552]] **Caused by: [Connection
>   refused: no further information: /192.168.0.99:2552]**

I believe I'm getting a connection refused error because there's nothing listening on port 2552, but I'm confused about why. How does the Akka program get put on the nodes and begin running? Why does it work with 127.0.0.1 and not my static IP?

As far as I can tell, no where in this tutorial or documentation does it explicitly say: "You need to compile a separate program for your nodes." So does the program get pushed to the nodes from the main Akka server or do I need to create another project for my nodes?

I'm guess the former, but then how/why are people doing their node development in the same project as their server? How are they running the same jar differently as a server and as a node?

EDIT:

```
Address of Raspberry Pi Node 1: 192.168.0.8
Address of Raspberry Pi Node 2: 192.168.0.9
Address of Desktop Computer: 192.168.0.99
```

application.conf on Desktop Computer (Note hostname)

```
#//#snippet
akka {

    log-dead-letters = off
    log-level = "debug"

  actor {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "192.168.0.99"
      port = 2552
    }
  }

  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@192.168.0.8:2552",
      "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@192.168.0.9:2552"]

    #//#snippet
    # excluded from snippet
    auto-down-unreachable-after = 10s
    #//#snippet
    # auto downing is NOT safe for production deployments.
    # you may want to use it during development, read more about it in the docs.
    #
    # auto-down-unreachable-after = 10s
  }
}

# Disable legacy metrics in akka-cluster.
akka.cluster.metrics.enabled=off

# Enable metrics extension in akka-cluster-metrics.
akka.extensions=["akka.cluster.metrics.ClusterMetricsExtension"]

# Sigar native library extract location during tests.
# Note: use per-jvm-instance folder when running multiple jvm on one host.
akka.cluster.metrics.native-library-extract-folder=${user.dir}/target/native
#//#snippet
```

application.conf on Raspberry Pi Node 2 (Similar on Node 1, just different hostname)

```
#//#snippet
akka {

    log-dead-letters = off
    log-level = "debug"

  actor {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "192.168.0.9"
      port = 2552
    }
  }

  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@192.168.0.8:2552",
      "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@192.168.0.9:2552"]

    #//#snippet
    # excluded from snippet
    auto-down-unreachable-after = 10s
    #//#snippet
    # auto downing is NOT safe for production deployments.
    # you may want to use it during development, read more about it in the docs.
    #
    # auto-down-unreachable-after = 10s
  }
}

# Disable legacy metrics in akka-cluster.
akka.cluster.metrics.enabled=off

# Enable metrics extension in akka-cluster-metrics.
akka.extensions=["akka.cluster.metrics.ClusterMetricsExtension"]

# Sigar native library extract location during tests.
# Note: use per-jvm-instance folder when running multiple jvm on one host.
akka.cluster.metrics.native-library-extract-folder=${user.dir}/target/native
#//#snippet
```

With this I get "No route to host" on the node as I try to bring it up.

EDIT 2:

Because main is at simple.sample.cluster.simple.SimpleClusterApp I have to launch my node with "java -cp cluster.jar simple.sample.cluster.simple.SimpleClusterApp". Does that seem right? I assume this is the same tutorial project I'm compiling/assembling for both the node and the desktop? Or do I need to create an entirely different project for my nodes?? I'm so confused. The tutorial is terrible for newcomers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hihi.

In this part of Akka Tutorial assumes you know how to up 2-nd node.

for this you need to start 2-nd actorSystem with .conf, where

```
 netty.tcp {
      hostname = "192.168.0.99"
      port = 2552
    }
```

and in seed write address of your 1-st node.

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping. See my edit for my conf files. I definitely don't know how to get my second node up! I tried generating a jar (using sbt assembly) for my node using its IP as the hostname but got "No route to host" when I tried to bring it up. I compiled my desktop version with the hostname as 192.168.0.99.

Comment: error in your fist config. netty.tcp {
      hostname = "192.168.0.99"
      port = 2552
    } hostname must be 192.168.0.8

Comment: oh. i got it. write all 3 nodes in every seed nodes.

Comment: the node from 0.9 don't know node from 0.99 and won't take the connect from her.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Could you amend your answer? Write all three nodes in which conf? The seed conf or the desktop conf, or both? And what if I don't want my desktop to be a node, just managing them?

Comment: all three nodes in every conf. I don't think you can make a cluster were "head" node is not actually a node.

Comment: Oh, okay. I think I'm getting somewhere!!! Looks like nodes are communicating, but there were some strange periods of being UNREACHABLE. Here is the run log from my desktop: http://pastebin.com/h7CxZUMx and here's the run log from one of the Pi's: http://pastebin.com/L0j9nKxi Does that look normal since the nodes were just establishing connection? Looks like they worked it out in the end. Logging stopped after they were connected.

Comment: you have a problem with nodes ports. config it and everything will be okay.

Comment: Can't I use the same port for everything now that I'm on different IP's? I get why I wouldn't be able to do that if I were running a cluster locally. This is basically what I'm doing in each now: http://screencast.com/t/liHh14aPhK

Comment: right, but try change port. 0 --> to 2551. in every conf